# Reading file line by line and inserting each word from a line to linked list in C

Tags: c, file, parsing

I have a text file with lots of line and string data, i.e., I don't know how many lines there are and how many words there are in each line.

So, I decided to do all things dynamically. I have a 2D linked list such as:

```
    struct Node
    {
      char word[50];
      struct Node* words;
      struct Node* next;
    }
```

My list:

```
Node -> Node("something") -> Node("something") //length is random
 |
 v
Node -> Node("something") -> Node("something") -> Node("something") //length is random
  .
  .
  .
```

My problem is parsing file. When I used `while( fscanf(file, "%s", word) == 1 )`, it takes words without checking the end of the line. When I wanted to use `fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)`, I needed to specify the size of the line, but I don't know the size of the line. My purpose is to insert words from a line until the end of that line, then I will create another node, and I will insert words from that line to the new node and so on.

How can I parse my file? Is there any other function?

Comment: You can use `fgets` to read a line and then `sscanf` or `strtok` to split it into words.

Comment: If using a compliant library, perhaps consider using [`getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/getline). It will *probably* do what you're asking, and dynamically allocates the line buffer memory per-line if you use it properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strtok` to split-up each line into seprate words. Just rememeber to `strcpy` each word from `strtok` as it doesn't make a copy, but rather edits the buffer and pointer manipulation to refrence different parts of the buffer.

```
> Buffer == "Hello there, how are you"

> word = strtok(Buffer, " ")

> Buffer == "Hello\0there, how are you" && word == &Buffer[0]

> word = strtok(NULL, " ")

> Buffer == "Hello\0there,\0how are you" && word == &Buffer[6]

> ect...
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE* in = fopen("myFile.txt", "r");
    
    char* buffer;
    char* word;
    size_t buffer_size = 0;
    
    getline(&buffer, &buffer_size, in);
    
    
    puts("The words from the first line are:");
    word = strtok(buffer, " ");
    while(word != NULL) {
        puts(word);
        word = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here's the same program working [at this site](https://onlinegdb.com/n3rORvpvC)

Comment: it gives that error : `undefined reference to getline`. I am using standard C.

Comment: Logan MacDougall, `getline()` is not part of the standard C library.